# how to create movable menu or link on web..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have seen ** [fluidicenergy.com](http://fluidicenergy.com)  **
and i am interested to create movable menu or link like that. i don't know how to make it..?

1. I have tried to save page to local, hope it made with "jquery".

i found script like this

```
<div class="canvas_container">
    <a name="breakthrough_anchor" id="breakthrough_anchor" class="named_anchor"></a>
    <canvas id="c_breakthrough" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;" width="1000" height="800">
        <h2>Breakthrough</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Integrated energy storage, electronics &amp; software on a simple platform</li>
            <li>Modular scalability onsite from kWh to MWh</li>
            <li><span class="OutagesCovered">571,153</span> commercial cycles</li>
            <li>Lowest cost energy storage for load shifting applications</li>
            <li>3x to 6x longer life, unaffected by hot environments &amp; harsh duty cycles</li>
        </ul>
    </canvas>
</div>
```

but, I still can't find the way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need  a 2D physics engine see: http://brm.io/matter-js/

Comment: Hi Sony, I have created almost same design with d3.js These link may help  you http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043 http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using some code of `jquery` and `javascript`.
Please follow the demo link:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)**